# update_cells not working as expected

Tags: gspread

I have written this function:

```
def duplicate_sheet1(wb, title=None):
    if title is None:
        title = wb.sheet1.title + ' DUPLICATE'

    wb._sheet_list = [wb.sheet1]

    wb.add_worksheet(title, wb.sheet1.row_count, wb.sheet1.col_count)
    wb._sheet_list = wb._sheet_list[::-1]

    wb._sheet_list[0].update_cells(wb._sheet_list[1]._fetch_cells())
```

...everything works as expected upon inspection with a debugger except `update_cells`, when I `_fetch_cells` for worksheet 0 after running the code, the sheet is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the list returned by `_fetch_cells` is not the same as what is expected by `update_cells`. This may be because `_fetch_cells` does not include empty cells in the returned list, `update_cells` may only work with a 1 or 2-D grid--I am unsure.

Here is the work-around I found, apologies as the code could could probably be improved:

```
def duplicate_sheet1(wb, title=None):
    if title is None:
        title = wb.sheet1.title + ' DUPLICATE'

    wb._sheet_list = [wb.sheet1]

    wb.add_worksheet(title, wb.sheet1.row_count, wb.sheet1.col_count)
    wb._sheet_list = wb._sheet_list[::-1]

    cell_list = build_cell_list(wb._sheet_list[0], wb._sheet_list[1])

    wb._sheet_list[0].update_cells(cell_list)


def build_cell_list(new_worksheet, old_worksheet):
    fetched = old_worksheet._fetch_cells()

    max_row = fetched[-1].row
    max_col = max([cell.col for cell in fetched])

    cell_list = new_worksheet.range('A1:' + chr(max_col + 64) + str(max_row))

    for cell in cell_list:
        cell.value = next(
            (
                f.value for f in fetched
                if f.col == cell.col and f.row == cell.row
            ),
            '',
        )

    return cell_list
```